# Makethis script to run commands

Tags: scripting, mirc

http://prntscr.com/w9fb4 
or

```
    on *:INPUT:#: {
  /set %ANSWER  $+ $1-
  /msg $active %ANSWER
  /unset %back.*
  /halt
}
```

So this remote turns all text we enter into bold....but we cant write commands(in the iput sector of the Chanel) in the Chanel when this script runs.How can i make it run the commands.
Any suggestions guys?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.

```
on *:input:*: {
  if (/* !iswm $1 || $ctrlenter) {
    say $+($chr(2),$1-)
    haltdef
  }
}
```